# How manually change locale of UIDatePicker in iOS?

Tags: ios, localization, uidatepicker, nslocale

How manually change `locale` in `UIDatePicker` control?

I have `UIDatePicker` and language selection inside my App which is independent from standard localisation in iOS (I mean from general settings of the device). I need to change `NSLocale` of the `UIDatePicker` from code.

How to do that?

Remark: on several places I've read that this can not be done - it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

only way to change the localization of the UIDatePicker is to change the device's language as I know.

Comment: You can, however, use a UIPickerView with multiple components to recreate a custom DatePicker that you can can the locale on by using an NSDateFormatter for the text in the components.